# Level Specific Access to pages on Django

Tags: django

I currently have a website that has three kinds of permissions:

1. Active
2. Staff
3. SuperUser

What I want to do is limit what a user can view depending on his subaccess level on Driver i.e. Driver has three sub access levels - 100, 200, 300. I was thinking of doing this by

```
    def email_check(user):
    return user.accesslevel

    @user_passes_test(accesslevel=100)
    def my_view(request):
       ...
```

How do I add the additional property of the subaccess level to the user model? Is there any other way to implement this? ALso, since this is a an already live project, there are a lot of user on-board already. I'll also need to provide them a default access value.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to go with `user_passes_test` looks good to me.

So your main issue is basically how to extend the user model. This topic is covered thoroughly under [Django documentation: Customizing authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/).

To sum up, there are mainly two ways to go with. One is to [extend your user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) with a custom model with an one-to-one relationship with User and any custom fields such as access level.

Alternatively, you can provide with a custom user model and [substitute the Django User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), but this seems not appropriate for your case.

Comment: What do you think about creating groups with no pre-defined permissions. And then checking the group name with the user_passes_test function? Based on the group name, grant permissions. I plan to have only one group per user which could act as the name of the access level. Do you think this is a viable solution?

Comment: It may be viable, but my advise is to keep it as much simple as possible.